# What's the difference between Color and Swatch in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Regarding the API (JSX or COM) there's the option to add Colors and Swatches. What's the difference? I see Color's that I add listed in the swatches panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swatch is a super class that embeds color, gradients, mixed inks or a mixed inks group. Color is just a member of that family.

> A swatch (color, gradient, tint, or mixed ink). Superclass of Color,
>   Gradient, MixedInk, and MixedInkGroup

http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Swatch.html